# Prove the set is a linearly independe subset of eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra

We already know A and B are similar matrices, $B=P^{-1}AP$. Let{$ x_{1}, x_{2}...x_{p}$} be a basis for $W_{A}$ (the eigenspace for A corresponding to  $\lambda$ ). and let $y_{i} =P^{-1}x_{i}$ for all $1\leq i\leq p$. Show that {$ y_{1}, y_{2},...,y_{p}$} is a linearly independent subset of $W_{B}$ (the eigenspace for B corresponding to  $\lambda$ )
Thank you.

Comment: actually this is the third question, I just prove if x $\in W_{A}$ then $y= P^{-1}x $, so $y \in W_{B}$. I have no clue on this question.

Answer (score 1):

if $\sum_k \alpha_k y_k= 0$ then we will have$\sum_i \alpha_i  y_{i} =\sum_i \alpha_i P^{-1}x_{i}=\sum_i P^{-1}\alpha_{i}x_{i}=P^{-1}\sum_i \alpha_i x_i=0$ and since $P^{-1}$ is invertable so $\sum_i \alpha_i x_i=0$and since $x_{i}$ are linear independent so we must have $\alpha_i=0$ for all i 
and so $\{y_i\}$ is linear independent

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\sum_k \alpha_k y_k = 0$. Multiplying by $P$, we have $P(\sum_k \alpha_k y_k) = \sum_k \alpha_k Py_k = \sum_k \alpha_k x_k = 0$. Since the $x_k$ form a basis, they are linearly independent, so $\alpha_k = 0$.

Comment: can you give me more specific explanation? I am still little bit confuse. Also are we able to to prove  $dim W_{A} \leq dim W_{B} $ from my question?

Comment: Well, it doesn't get much more specific than the above. What are you confused by? To show the $y_k$ are linearly independent, you need to show that if $\sum_k \alpha_k y_k =0$, then $\alpha_k=0$. It follows that $\dim W_B \ge p = \dim W_A$ from this.

Comment: The latter statement follows because the dimension is the maximum number of linearly independent vectors in the space.

Comment: what is $ \alpha _{k}$ from?

Comment: How do you define linearly independent?